# How to check if tree is symmetric python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, binary-tree

For practice, I solved Leetcode [101. Symmetric Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/) question:

> Given a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (ie, symmetric around its center).

I have an idea to do in order traversal, record each node value into list and check the value from the first part, and reverse the second part from the list. But
it failed on test case **[1,2,3,3,null,2,null]**
from my local, my value return **[3, 2, None, 1, 2, 3, None]**, but from leetcode it return **[3,2,1,2,3]** anyone know why and anything wrong with my code?

```
def isSymmetric(root: 'TreeNode') -> 'bool':

    if not root: return True
    value = []

    def traversal(cur):
        if cur:
            traversal(cur.left)
            value.append(cur.val)
            traversal(cur.right)

    traversal(root)
    size = int(len(value) / 2)
    return value[:size] == value[size + 1:][-1::-1]
```

Comment: It seems like your local tree does not match the tree used by leetcode. Does your local tree contain nodes with `self.val is None`?

Comment: yes...but refer @Kevin He 's answer. i am wrong inorder traversal cannt determine if tree is symmetric

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid inorder traversal does not uniquely determine a tree. e.g. a tree with structure

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
```

has the same inorder traversal as

```
  2
 / \
1   3
```

Since you have the `if cur` condition, your inorder traversal won't include null nodes, which makes the traversal non-unique. You can include the null nodes like this:

```
 def traverse(cur):
     if cur:
         traverse(cur.left)
     values.append(cur.val if cur else None)
     if cur:
         traverse(cur.right)
```

This would serialize the tree nodes uniquely.

What you can also do is in this case determine the structure of the left node and right node are the same (except left and right are reversed). Here is my accepted solution:

```
class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root: 'TreeNode') -> 'bool':
        if not root:
            return True
        return self.isSymmetricHelper(root.left, root.right)

    def isSymmetricHelper(self, node1, node2):
        if node1 is None and node2 is None:
            return True
        if node1 is None or node2 is None:
            return False
        if node1.val != node2.val: # early stopping - two nodes have different value
            return False 
        out = True
        out = out and self.isSymmetricHelper(node1.left, node2.right)
        if not out: # early stopping
            return False
        out = out and self.isSymmetricHelper(node1.right, node2.left)
        return out
```

It recursively check if two trees are the mirror of each other (with some early stopping). The idea is if two trees are mirror, the left subtree of tree1 must be the mirror of the right subtree of tree2, same applies for right subtree of tree1 and left subtree of tree2.

Although the runtime of both are O(n), he recursive method takes O(logn) average space (used by call stack) and has early stopping built-in, while your serialize-all-nodes method takes O(n) space O(n) time.

Comment: `You can include the null nodes like this:` - this will fail on `cur.val` as `cur` is `None`

Answer (score 0):

this is how the symmetric tree is:

[image]

```
class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        def is_mirror(t1,t2):
            # If I reached all the way down that means I always got True.
            if t1 is None and t2 is None:
                return True
            # if one of them is None but other one is not then False
            if t1 is None or t2 is None:
                return False
            # 2=2 and t1.left==t2.right and t1.right==t2.left
            return t1.val==t2.val and is_mirror(t1.left,t2.right) and is_mirror(t1.right,t2.left)
        return is_mirror(root.left,root.right)
```